# SQL как извлечь AUTOINCREMENT при вставлении новой строки

Tags: sql, sqlite

я использую столбец с AUTOINCREMENT чтобы каждая строка имела собственный идентификатор. И мне нужно как то узнавать его при создании новой строки, можно ли это как нибудь сделать?

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid

Comment: @Akina, оформите комментарий как ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть на системную таблицу sqlite_sequence. Ваша база данных sqlite будет иметь эту таблицу автоматически, если вы создали любую таблицу с автоинкрементным первичным ключом. Эта таблица предназначена для sqlite для отслеживания поля автоинкремента, чтобы он не повторял первичный ключ даже после удаления некоторых строк или после неудачной вставки ([подробнее об этом здесь](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc%20.html)).

Таким образом, с этой таблицей есть дополнительное преимущество, заключающееся в том, что вы можете узнать первичный ключ вновь вставленного элемента, даже после того, как вставили что-то еще (в других таблицах, конечно!). Убедившись, что вставка прошла успешно (в противном случае вы получите ложное число), вам просто нужно сделать:

```
select seq from sqlite_sequence where name="table_name"
```

Если использовать функцию **last_insert_rowid()**, то результат таким же, потому что если выполняется INSERT в базу данных во время работы функции **last_insert_rowid()** то это изменяет последний идентификатор строки вставки, и возвращаемое **last_insert_rowid()**, непредсказуемо и может не совпадать ни со старым, ни с новым последним rowid.

Comment: Представьте, что между вставкой и чтением другой клиент вставил в эту таблицу ещё одну запись...

Comment: я же написал об этом.

Comment: Эммм... где??? процитируйте, пожалуйста - я в упор не вижу ничего про конкурентные вставки.

Comment: второй абзац: там написано что это не будет работать)

Comment: Видимо, я таки ослеп. Ибо не вижу ни цитаты, которую я просил, ни слов "это не будет работать" во втором абзаце... Ладно, хрен с им.

Comment: А вот последний абзац (не помню, был ли раньше) - больше похож на фактическую ошибку. Ибо поведение состояния sqlite_sequence и last_insert_rowid() принципиально различны, а тут они объявляются чуть ли не алиасами.